# Symfony3 - normal route is interpreted as a route with parameters/slugs

Tags: routes, slug, symfony

I have the following routes defined in my app:

```
-------------------------- ---------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
 Name                       Method     Scheme   Host   Path
-------------------------- ---------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
 _wdt                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}
 _profiler_home             ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/
 _profiler_search           ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search
 _profiler_search_bar       ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar
 _profiler_info             ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/info/{about}
 _profiler_phpinfo          ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo
 _profiler_search_results   ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results
 _profiler                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}
 _profiler_router           ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router
 _profiler_exception        ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception
 _profiler_exception_css    ANY        ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
 _twig_error_test           ANY        ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}
 api_route                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /api
 sec_events_index           GET        ANY      ANY    /sec/events/
 sec_events_new             GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /sec/events/new
 sec_events_show            GET        ANY      ANY    /sec/events/{id}
 sec_events_edit            GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /sec/events/{id}/edit
 sec_guest_delete           ANY        ANY      ANY    /sec/guest/{id}
 sec_events_delete          DELETE     ANY      ANY    /sec/events/{id}
 pub_event                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /{id}/{guestid}
 home_page                  ANY        ANY      ANY    /
 about_page                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /about
 products_route             ANY        ANY      ANY    /products
 sec_guests_new             GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /sec/guests/new
 sec_guests_edit            GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /sec/guests/{id}/edit
 send_invite                ANY        ANY      ANY    /sec/invites
 admin_index                GET        ANY      ANY    /admin/users
 profile_show               ANY        ANY      ANY    /sec/profile
 admin_edit                 GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /admin/{id}/edit
 sec_delete                 DELETE     ANY      ANY    /admin/{id}
 login_route                ANY        ANY      ANY    /login
 login_check                ANY        ANY      ANY    /login_check
 pass_reset                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /reset
 pass_reset_form            ANY        ANY      ANY    /{token}
 test                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /test
 homepage                   ANY        ANY      ANY    /
 logout                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /logout
-------------------------- ---------- -------- ------ -----------------------------------
```

Whenever I access route `profile_show` via browser with `/sec/profile` the profiler tells me it tries to access route `pub_event` as if I had typed `/{id}/{guestid}` in my browser. 
Is there something I am doing wrong to make it pick up the proper route and the correct controller and method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your route `pub_event` at end of imported routes in `routing.yml`.

This is normal behaviour as `/sec/profile` matches `/{id}/{guestid}`. Good practice is to load generic routes at end of `routing.yml` file.

Other thing what you can do is setting requirement for `id` parameter in `pub_event` route.

With annotations it should look like that:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/{guestid}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"}, defaults={"id" = 1})
 */
```

Remember that "Earlier Routes always Win". Read more about requirements in Symfony Routing book: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#adding-requirements

Comment: Can't stress this enough.  Rather than just putting all of your routes like this at the end of your routing files, which may not work if you're using annotations, you should set stricter requirements on your routes so that some routes may not match others.  I would recommend changing your `pub_event` route to `/event/{id}/{guestid}` for extra insurance and for SEO clarity.

Comment: [Prefixed routes](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html#prefixing-imported-routes) would be a good idea in such situations :) .